# Understanding Elm's Type Signature return types

Tags: functional-programming, elm

I am trying to understand elm's type signatures.  What does this function return exactly?  It appears to be a function that accepts no arguments and returns ...

```
route : Parser (Page -> a) a
```

Comment: Can you add a reference to where this is coming from?

Comment: Line 22 from [this example app](https://github.com/AdrianRibao/elm-spa-example/blob/master/main.elm) . thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a learning exercise for myself I'm going to try to answer this. Others will chip in if I get something wrong.

I'm sure you are used to something like

```
type Person = Adult String | Child String Age
```

Child is a type that takes two parameters. Parser is the same. But it's [definition](https://github.com/evancz/url-parser/blob/2.0.1/src/UrlParser.elm#L35) is pretty formidable

```
type Parser a b =
  Parser (State a -> List (State b))


type alias State value =
  { visited : List String
  , unvisited : List String
  , params : Dict String String
  , value : value
  }
```

That said, you see how Parser is ultimately a wrapper around a function from a State to a list of States. Ultimately it is going to be passed a List of 'unvisited' strings or params; it will progressively 'visit' each one and the result will be combined into the final 'value'.

Next, note that while Parser takes two type parameters - `a`, `b` - `parseHash` is defined

```
parseHash : Parser (a -> a) a -> Location -> Maybe a
```

So, your original

```
route : Parser (Page -> a) a
```

is going to have to be

```
route : Parser (Page -> Page) Page
```

to type check.

To return to your original question, therefore, `route` is a Parser (which is a very general object) that encapsulates instructions on how to go from one `Page` to another, and can be used - via parseHash - to tell you what `Page` to go to next, and that is of course what you would expect from a router.

Hope this gets you started